# How to get the confidence of a prediction from a MLModel (Machine Learning Model) in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, machine-learning, coreml

even though my code is pretty simplistic in what it is trying to do, basically I want to have the classifier model return an accuracy/confidence value for how accurate it thinks it's prediction is, **on actual Xcode application (not playground) please**.

I'm using a made-up Dog breed Classifier which is Text Classifier as an example:

Code:

```
do {

  if try DogClassiferModel().prediction(text: "value").confidence >= 90 {

  print("We have a high enough accuracy that this is the name of a dog breed")

  }

} catch let error {

  print(error)
}
```

I know in Xcode's playground you can do this with test data:

Code:

```
  let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "Path"))

  let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)

  let testClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "recognized")

  // Getting the testing evaluation.
  let evaluationMetrics = testClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData)
  let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100

  // We can print the accuracy with print(evaluationAccuracy).
```

**Thought: Maybe CoreML doesn't work like the way I am trying to do it I don't know?**

Comment: Were you able to find the way to get confidence value? If you can tell, that would be helpful because the accepted answer didn't help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write,

```
try DogClassiferModel().prediction(text: "value")
```

what is returned is a `DogClassiferModelOutput` object. If your model's output is named `confidence`, you can get it by writing:

```
if let output = try DogClassiferModel().prediction(text: "value") {
  print(output.confidence)
}
```

However, classifier models in Core ML are usually treated in a special way. They can return the label of the highest scoring class, or a dictionary containing the probabilities for all the labels.

The best way to find out how this works for your model, is to look at the mlmodel file in Xcode, click the arrow to go the automatically generated source code file, and look for the "Output" class. This will have one or more properties that you can access (like shown in the example above).

Comment: Should a boosted tree model have a confidence property? If not is there an option to add it in the training in CreateML?

Comment: I am unable to find any confidence property. Can you please help?

Comment: It probably has a different name in your model.

Comment: How can I check that? Is there a way sir I can contact you? So that I can resolve my issue? I have tried many things but unable to fix the issue. May be because I am new in this.

Comment: You can choose this name when you convert the model using the coremltools utilities. The docs explain how to do this (or check out my book, see my profile).

Comment: Sir I am not converting the model. I am training the model in Create ML app. In that app, I am not finding any option to add confidence in the output. There is no option of adding screenshot here in comments otherwise I would have shown you.

Comment: Ah, I missed we were talking about a Create ML Text Classifier here. That does not output a confidence, only the predicted label.

Answer (score 0):

Hers is also another way to do that.
You can get the confidence percentage by below code

```
let probs = output.classLabelProbs[output.classLabel]
    
self.confidence = probs ?? 0.0 //Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
```